# Typo3 4.5.5 update and rgsmoothgallery 1.5.2 no gallery?

Tags: php, typo3

After a T3 update from T3 4.1.3 to 4.5.5. my rgsmoothgallery is black in the front-end? There isn't any error in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have Mootools 1.21 (ext :    t3mootools  1.3.0) ?
i can't make rgsmoothgallery 1.5.2 working with mootools ...
you can look this (in german)
http://bingprofi.blogspot.com/2009/10/typo3-rgsmoothgallery-mit-mootools-121.html

but i don't understand how to do...

Comment: It happens to me that Mootools was a compressed library. I replaced it with the uncompressed library.